# how to find if the last li is active in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am repeating the li using ng-repeat in this i need to find the last li active, if the last li is active i need to disable the prev button.

```
<div class="pagination">
    <button ng-disabled="start == 0" ng-click="prevPage()">Prev</button>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myNumber)  | limitTo: pagerStep track by $index" ng-class="{active: $index == selected}" ng-click="select($index)">
        <button ng-click="loadFromMenu($index+1)" ng-class="pageList">
          {{$index+1}}
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-disabled="start == lastStart" ng-click="nextPage()">Next</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another parameter to the `select()` function: `isLast`, and call it from the view `ng-click="select($index, $last)"` Then you could raise another flag that indicate if the last clicked element was the last in the `ngRepeat` and use that flag to disable the prev button:

View:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <button ng-disabled="start == 0" ng-click="prevPage()">Prev</button>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myNumber)  | limitTo: pagerStep track by $index" ng-class="{active: $index == selected}" ng-click="select($index, $last)">
        <button ng-click="loadFromMenu($index+1)" ng-class="pageList">
          {{$index+1}}
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-disabled="isLast" ng-click="nextPage()">Next</button>
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.select = function(selectedIndex, isLast) {
   $scope.selected = selectedIndex;
   $scope.isLast = isLast;
   // And the rest of your code of course 
}
```